# Getting hibernate persistent object at the time of pre update event

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am implementing pre update event listener in java hibernate 4.3.
I need to get old persistent object value before update occures.
I have tried using `event.getOldState()` in PreUpdateEventListener. But it gives Object[] as return type. I want the persistent object as return value.

How to get complete persistent object in preUpdateEvent?
The preUpdateEventListener is implemented correctly.
Just need to get Complete persisted object instead i get Object[].

Also tried `event.getSession().get(id,persisted.class);`  //this gives new object as session has set new object to update

Below is code that gives Object[]

```
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEventListener;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEvent;
public class MyEventListener implements PreUpdateEventListener  {
    public void onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event)  {
        Object newEntity=event.getEntity();    //Gives new Object which will be updated.
        Object[] oldEntity=evetn.getOldState();    //gives old Object[] which can't be converted to persisted Object
        //Code here which will give me old persisted objects, hibernate fetches object in array format.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i remember well the object array contains all attribute values of given entity :
the index of the associated property can be resolved using the property name array

```
 String[] propertyNames = event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel.getPropertyNames();
```

this [link](http://anshuiitk.blogspot.fr/2010/11/hibernate-pre-database-opertaion-event.html) may be usefull

Comment: Thanks your answer is very helpfull. According to post i write method which builds the entity using Object[].

Comment: @Gab bruh you're answer was very helpful, BUT WHY THO !! why they have to make this difficult? why not returning at least `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Object[]` !!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how listeners work with pure Hibernate, but if you use JPA event listeners, the entity is passed as a parameter to the listener method:

```
public class MyUpdateListener {

  @PreUpdate
  public void onPreUpdate(MyEntiy e) {
    e.getAttribute();
    // do something
  }
 ...
```

If you define a listener method inside the entity, you can simply access the state of `this`

```
@PreUpdate
public void onPreUpdate() {
  getAttribute();
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Annotations does not work as i am using xml based mapping. That's why i can't use JPA annotations for event handling.

Comment: JPA listeners can be defined in XML as well. But I see you have got your answer already :)